# Why are the Android runtime and native libraries in the same layer?

Tags: architecture, android, layers, runtime

Regarding the diagram in Android's website: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform

Why did they put the Android Runtime category in the same layer as the native C/C++ libraries category. Shouldn't they be one on top of the other?

[image: Platform Architecture]

Comment: You are asking why some person drew a diagram in a specific way. The only person who can tell you why they drew the diagram in that way, is the person who drew it. You need to ask them, not us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That layer is for components that support `Java API Framework` interface with the `Hardware Abstraction Layer`. Components in `Java API Framework` utilize both `Native C/C++ Libraries` and `Android Runtime`.